# How to avoid while in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have this expression:

```kotlin
var previousState = state.previousState
while (previousState != null && previousState::class != searchClass) {
    previousState = previousState.previousState
}
```

Can I do it without `while` and `var` in kotlin way?

Comment: Can you show a little more code? How does the type of `state` look?

Comment: It's either Java or Kotlin, not both.

Comment: why do you need `while` here? By looking at this code, it seems to be updating the value of `previousState` only once. If the code is executed repetitively, then just use `if` instead of `while`.

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi It appears to be walking through something like a linked list.

Comment: @JeroenJK, probably `Java` was there to specify that it's `Kotlin-on-JVM`. Not `JavaScript` or `LLVM` versions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this will work out:

```
val seq = generateSequence(state.previousState) { previousState ->
  previousState.previousState
}
val result = seq.firstOrNull { it::class == searchClass }
```

Answer (score 1):

What is *kotlin way*?
Make your algorithm a recursive function, and it will work in any language without `while`:

```
private tailrec fun previousState(state: State?) : State? {
    if(state != null && state::class != searchClass) {
        return previousState(state.previousState)
    }

    return state
}
```

Comment: In `Java`, for example, we don't have tail recursion,

Comment: I meant tail recursion optimization.

Comment: @ВасилийНикпуп *`JVM`, not `Java`, also, look at this: https://medium.com/coding-blocks/tail-call-optimization-in-jvm-with-kotlin-ebdf90b34ec9